# Non-smooth 3D surface plot using PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to draw a graph like this
[image: needed plot]

I came up with a close-up representation, but it's too smooth

```
# Scene setup
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.view_init(40, 130)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2, 2, 10), np.linspace(-2, 2, 10))
z = phase(activation(cm_num))

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

[image: my plot]

How can I get that stairs-like shape, or maybe I should use polar coordinates?

Additional notes: z is an 10x10 numpy array

```
array([[3.77, 3.77, 3.77, 3.77, 4.4 , 4.4 , 5.03, 5.03, 5.03, 5.03],
       [3.77, 3.77, 3.77, 3.77, 4.4 , 4.4 , 5.03, 5.03, 5.03, 5.03],
       [3.14, 3.14, 3.77, 3.77, 4.4 , 4.4 , 5.03, 5.03, 5.65, 5.65],
       [3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.77, 3.77, 5.03, 5.03, 5.65, 5.65, 5.65],
       [3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.77, 5.03, 5.65, 5.65, 5.65, 5.65],
       [2.51, 2.51, 2.51, 2.51, 1.88, 0.63, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [2.51, 2.51, 2.51, 1.88, 1.88, 0.63, 0.63, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [2.51, 2.51, 1.88, 1.88, 1.26, 1.26, 0.63, 0.63, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [1.88, 1.88, 1.88, 1.88, 1.26, 1.26, 0.63, 0.63, 0.63, 0.63],
       [1.88, 1.88, 1.88, 1.88, 1.26, 1.26, 0.63, 0.63, 0.63, 0.63]])
```

Comment: Maybe `z = floor(n_steps * arctan(y/(2*x)))`??

Comment: @Scott I tried your option, it does not work. Also z is a defined function of x and y, so I can't use arctan etc. As you can see from the provided matrix, values are routed around the center, so I just need to display them properly.

Comment: ohhhhh, you've already got the z values!  A lot of matplotlib methods have an `interpolation` option... Maybe `interpolation = nearest`, or some other interpolation will help?

Comment: May also be useful to simply interpolate yourself by increasing the steps in the meshgrid.  Maybe try 100 or so.

Comment: @Scott Well, `interpolation` is an unknown property for the `plot_surface` function.
When I try increasing step up to the 1/1000 the plot becomes absolutely smooth [plot](https://imgur.com/Z4mM4PE).

Comment: Sounds like your `x,y,z` data don't actually form a staircase...